# From which rails version supports json data of postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just would like to know from which rails version supports json data of postgres.
Does rails 2.3.5 support json data?

I googled and looked for the articles, but I could not find ones.
It would be highly appreciated if you would share the information with me.

Answer (score 0):

You find the changes in the changelog of each version

So, in the change of rails 4.2 version, the postgresql adapter have added support for jsonb columns

The PostgreSQL adapter now supports the jsonb datatype in PostgreSQL 9.4+.

Here is the link https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html